# Echo PHP variable under a Wordpress custom Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, variables

I have a custom field as an option, and I want to put the value of this option in a custom loop.

So here's what I have:

```
$CatTxt = the_field('section_1', 'option'); 
            echo $CatTxt;
```

This works, the problem is when I try to put on the loop. My attempts:

Double quotes - doesn't work:

```
<?php query_posts("category_name=$CatTxt"); ?>
```

Separating with the dot - Doesn't' work:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.$CatTxt); ?>
```

Any idea on how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the ACF plugin? Cause "the_field" function outputs the data. You should be using "get_field" function which returns data and assigns it to a variable. Then combine this with what @Ognjen wrote and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this now please:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.'"$CatTxt"'); ?>
```